# Tomcat Sending Invalid SSL Certificate to Client

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install SSL certificates on tomcat on Windows 2012 R2 server . I followed the normal procedure:

1. created keystore
2. generated csr
3. got certificates from Godaddy
4. imported certificates into the keystore
5. updated server.xml with the correct values
6. restarted tomcat

However , when I run the URL it is pointing to some self signed root certificate.

I tried clearing tomcat cache but it is not working . I am looking for suggestions what might be preventing tomcat from sending the correct certificate ?

Comment: Is the alias name specified in the server.xml is correct?.

Comment: @StackPlayer yes problem was in the alias name . I forgot to mention it . thanks for letting me know .